# Read the sql files by Exclude the list of files from sql table and Execute all the files in a single Transaction using PowerShell

Tags: sql, sql-server, powershell, transactions

I have not an Expert in power shell. I Need a script/Approch which handles the below requirement.

I have list of files in a folder and the file Names like below.

```
001_File.sql
002_File.sql
003_File.sql
004_File.sql
```

Also, I have a table in sql server which holds the file Name Information.

**TableName**: Executedfile with a column FileName.

```
002_File.sql
004_File.sql
```

My requirement is to read the files which is **available in the folder but not in the table**.

I have to the Read files only:

```
001_File.sql
003_File.sql
```

Now, I Need to Execute these two file in the sequential order under the same Transaction on SQL Server. As I Need to rollback all the transaction if any Error occurred.

As of now I wrote a power shell something below.

```
$QueryResult = Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance 'MyServer' -Database 'MyDb' -Query "SELECT DISTINCT FNames from TableName"

Get-ChildItem "E:\Testing\" -Filter *.sql | Sort-Object $_.Name|
Foreach-Object {
    $FileFullpath= $_.FullName

     Write-Host $FileFullpath

     $FileName = $_.Name

     Write-Host $FileName

     if(!$QueryResult.FName.Contains($FileName))
     {
        invoke-sqlcmd -inputfile $FileFullpath -serverinstance "servername\serverinstance" -database "mydatabase"
     }

}
```

Please suggest me some script.

Challenges:

1. How to read the files in Sequential order as it has leading Zeros. Does the Above `Sort-Object $_.Name ' will Sort ?
2. How to Execute all the list of files under one transaction.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I wrote the Script using SMO Objects to handle the GO Statement and Transactions.

```
$SqlFilePath = "D:\Roshan\Testing\SQL\"

$serverName = "MyServer"
$databaseName = "MyDB"

$QueryResult = Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance $serverName -Database $databaseName -Query "SELECT DISTINCT FName from dbo.TableName" -AS DataRows

$connection = new-object system.data.SqlClient.SQLConnection("Data Source=$serverName;Integrated Security=SSPI;Initial Catalog=$databaseName;Connection Timeout=600;Max Pool Size=10"); 
$Server = new-Object Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server(New-Object Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.ServerConnection($connection))

$script_contents ="SET XACT_ABORT ON
                GO
                BEGIN TRANSACTION 
                GO"


Get-ChildItem $SqlFilePath -Filter *.sql| Sort-Object $_.Name|

ForEach-Object {

if(!$QueryResult.FName.Contains($_.Name))
{
    Write-Host $_.Name -ForegroundColor Magenta

    #[string]$script_contents = Get-Content $_.FullName
    $script_contents += [IO.File]::ReadAllText($_.FullName)

   #Write-Host $script_contents
   #$Server.ConnectionContext.ExecuteNonQuery($script_contents)
} 

} 

$script_contents+= " COMMIT TRANSACTION;"

$Server.ConnectionContext.ExecuteNonQuery($script_contents)
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally I did something like this.

```
 $QueryResult = Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance 'MyServer' -Database 'MyDb' -Query "SELECT DISTINCT FNames from TableName"

 $FullScript = @()
 $FullScript += "BEGIN TRANSACTION;"


Get-ChildItem "E:\Testing\" -Filter *.sql | Sort-Object $_.Name|
Foreach-Object {

 if(!$QueryResult.FName.Contains($_.Name))
 {
    $FullScript += Get-Content $_.FullName
 }
}

$FullScript += "COMMIT TRANSACTION;"

sqlcmd -S localhost -d test -Q "$FullScript"
```

Comment: This is not Working. As My files had go statement in the Middle.

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
#get list of filenames from database...
$QueryResult = Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance 'MyServer' -Database 'MyDB' -Query "SELECT DISTINCT FNames from TableName" | Select-Object -ExpandProperty FileName

#get files from folder whose names are not in $queryresult...
$files = Get-ChildItem -Path E:\Testing -Filter *.sql | ? {(!($QueryResult.Contains($_.BaseName)))} | Sort-Object Name

#get the content of each $file and replace "GO" with empty string, etc...
$queries = @()

foreach ($file in $files) {

    $queries += (Get-Content $file.FullName).replace("GO","")

}

#join each query into a single T-SQL statement...
$singleTransaction = $queries -join ";"

#execute statement...
Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance 'SERVER' -Database 'DB' -Query $singleTransaction
```

To really achieve a 'single transaction'...you may have to have a consistent input to modify and put into one statement. I am not sure how you will need to do that.

Comment: We can't replace all the GO Statements. As it Needed in Some Scenarios where I have Alter statement and Update stmt on a single Column of the table without GO Statement it will throw me an Error.

Comment: Sure, it was only an example. This is how you will do what you asked - but managing the SQL statement itself will be a different issue. No one has your code, so there is no way to help there.

Answer (score -1):

You can write some thing in your shell script

```
select filename from tablename; >> file.out
--->002_File.sql

grep -v 'file.out' * >> excludedfile.out
```

Comment: Which environment would allow one to redirect SQL select statement's results into file as per your example?